# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'w'

Tags: python, module, undefined

I'm making a BMI calculator for my intro to programming class, I'm trying to work ahead and learn how to use modules. I'm trying to implement a system where the user is only allowed to input integers.

I haven't tried much and haven't been able to find a simply worded answer so here I am.

```
def Run():
    bmi = ((int(valcheckw.w) * 703)/(int(valcheckh.h)*int(valcheckh.h))

def valcheckw():
    w = (input('weight(Lbs):'))
    try: 
        val0 = int(w)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int!")
        del w
        valcheckw()

def valcheckh():
    h = (input('height in inches'))
    try:
        val = int(h)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int!")
        del h
        valcheckh()

valcheckw()
valcheckh()
Run()
```

In `Run()` I expected it to just pull the variables `w`, and `h` from their respective modules but instead I get an error saying that they are not defined.

Comment: There is only one module here with several functions. The variables like `w` are local to those functions, they aren't attributes of those functions

Comment: Note also, your `del` statements don't do anything. Local variables cease to exist when the function terminates anyway

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the results (`val0` & `val1`) of the two functions (`valcheckw` & `valcheckh`) in order to access them within the `run` function.

You also need to determine whether the input data is in fact a number vs some other type. You can utilize the `float` function for this.

Something like the below might help you model how to properly achieve the result you are looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def valcheckw():
    w=input('weight(lbs): ')
    try:
        val0=float(w)
        return val0
    except ValueError:
        print('That\'s not a number!')
        valcheckw()

def valcheckh():
    h=input('height(in): ')
    try:
        val1=float(h)
        return val1
    except ValueError:
        print('That\'s not a number!')
        valcheckh()

def run():
    weight=valcheckw()
    height=valcheckh()
    bmi=float(weight * 703/float(height*height))
    print(bmi)

### main ###
run()
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this code is not correct, and doesn't address the OPs fundamental confusion.